# how should i start new line in a String text in React?

Tags: reactjs

i try'd to use \n but its not working. any ideas?

```
  {
name: "learn-teambuilding",
title: "What Do We Know about Software Development in 
Startups?",
content: [
'• use of easy-to-implement tools to facilitate product development Nevertheless, the absence of structure might hinder important activities.\ntest'
 ]  
},
```

Comment: You can use string interpolation i.e backticks `\` LONG STRING IN MULTIPLE LINES \``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok and already works for me ! you can also use back tick (this symbol: ``) and put your string in it